# Remove all value duplicates in array

Tags: c#, arrays

example array:

```
int[] s new = {1,2,3,1};
```

if use:

```
int[] inew = snew.Distinct().ToArray();
```

then out put:

```
{1,2,3}
```

but I want out put:

```
{2,3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select everything where duplicate count is == 1:

```
snew.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToArray();
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ODCm9K)

Comment: Ahh, slowly you're coming to a solution... FGITW, hmm?

Comment: Group is much cleaner than your initial answer :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller yeah sorry, I was going by memory then slowly changing my answer every time I realized my mistakes haha. Then I just went on dotnetfiddle and figured out the right syntax.